How to Resolve SLF4J Compatibility Issues with Logback 1.5 and Logback 1.2 Dependencies
I'm currently upgrading the hapi-fhir version to 6.8.8, which has upgraded slf4j-api to 2.x. This new version uses the ServiceLoader mechanism for class loading. My application uses Logback 1.5, which is compatible with the new SLF4J mechanism. However, some libraries in my project still use Logback 1.2, and I cannot update these dependencies to Logback 1.5 as it is beyond my control.
This version mismatch is causing issues, and I am encountering the following error:  
I found that SLF4J provides bridging modules to redirect calls made to other logging APIs (like log4j 1.x, JCL, and java.util.logging) to behave as if they were made to the SLF4J API. This information is available on the SLF4J Legacy page.
Is there a similar solution for logback-classic to handle this compatibility issue? How can I overcome this problem without switching to log4j?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
PS: I'm using Springboot 2.7.x and I don't need to update it due to some another reasons.

"some libraries in my project still use Logback 1.2": can you clarify this statement? Libraries do not usually depend on a logging implementation (like Logback), but just a logging API (Commons Logging, SLF4J, Log4j API). The logging implementation is only added as direct runtime dependency of the application. Can you add the list of your dependencies to the question?

springboot dependencies use logback 1.2. (Couldn't mention that my springboot version is 2.7.x and i don't need to update it). But because of HAPI FHIR, i need logback 1.5. switching to logback 1.5 break springboot due to compatibility issue. Currently I have fixed the issue by strictly using logback 1.2 for the both springboot and hapifhir. but i don't think it is a good idea.

Can you add your Maven or Gradle configuration to the question? Are you using spring-boot-starter-parent? Did you try pinning your dependencies to SLF4J 2.x and Logback 1.5.x?

"don't need to update" ?  https://endoflife.date/spring-boot    and   https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.7.17     are you not concerned about no support and vulnerabilities?  with a FHIR server, with healthcare data?
